# Addon sidebar in Sheets doesn't show any addons

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a Google Workspace Addon for the editors in G Suite (Docs & Sheets). I am able to get the addon homepage icon to appear in the sidebar for docs. However, I cannot achieve this in Sheets and I have no idea why.

I have tried installing other Google Workspace Addons in Sheets, such as Box, and they do not appear in the sidebar either.

I have tried this in two G Suite environments, my work one, and a clean trial one a setup. Same problem.

Any ideas?

The onHomepage function for Sheets does exactly what the documentation says to do. It builds a Card and returns it.

Manifest file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/London",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "serviceId": "drive",
        "version": "v2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.currentonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify", "https://mail.google.com/", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/", "https://*.document-safe.com/", "https://www.google.co.uk/" ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "DM Integration",
      "logoUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qb4TXjS2FAFiNsLn3G2zRmrPswYLQBQE/view?usp\u003dsharing"
    },
    "gmail": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "gmailOnHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "docs": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "docsOnHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "sheetsOnHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Screenshot of Sheets
[Screenshot showing no addons appearing in sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHHt3.png)

Thanks

Comment: Note: I am using a business account. I just tried installing Box on a personal account, and the addon appeared in the sidebar. Is there something the administrator of the business G Suite environment needs to configure?

Comment: This seems to be a bug. There is an issue tracker entry for it [linked here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170819044). Please star the issue to bring more attention to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

Issue is fixed. The addon should show now.

---

#### This issue is a reported bug here:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/170819044.

Please click on the star icon to give it more visibility.