# Google Sheets Workspace Add-on versus Editor Add-on for custom functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, custom-function

I have a published `Editor Add-on` for Google Sheets. It is deployed via the `Sheets Add-on` section within the `App Configuration` page of the Google Workplace Marketplace service on GCP.

I have been thinking about moving it to a `Workspace Add-on` in order to make use of the Card functionality. However, I haven't been able to confirm that the latter is actually able to *use* custom functions. For example, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types says:

> Each Editor Add-on type (for example, Sheets add-ons) can have its own set of type-specific capabilities, restrictions, and special considerations. When building Editor Add-ons, it's important to understand these Editor-specific details

And going to the Sheets page, mentions custom functions. It also doesn't help that there seems to be no way to actually test the custom functions are working via either method of testing due to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763437 without having a published `Editor Add-on`. So I haven't been able to confirm this way either.

Are Google `Workspace Add-on` a *replacement* to the current `Editor Add-on`? I.e. can I check/use the `Google Workspace Add-on` option and uncheck the `Sheets Add-on`? Or do I need to use *both*, the `Workspace Add-on` for the Card feature and `Editor Add-on` for custom functions?

Comment: You can publish and see if yourself, why don't you do it?

Comment: [There was a issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210634/addon-sidebar-in-sheets-doesnt-show-any-addons), but I believe it should work as a replacement now, but I'm not sure about custom functions or triggers.

Comment: I don't think those triggers are available with Workspace Add-On. For me on the load trigger wasn't happening. For now one has to use HtmlService for the layout